# Scipy curve_fit: how to plot the fitted curve beyond the data points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a number of data points and I used Scipy `curve_fit` to fit a curve to this data set. I now would like to plot the fit ***beyond*** the range of data points and I cannot find out how to do it.

Here is a simple example based on an exponential fitting:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([30, 50, 80, 160, 300, 580])
fitting_parameters, covariance = curve_fit(exponential_fit, x, y)
a, b, c = fitting_parameters

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x, exponential_fit(x, *fitting_parameters), '-', label='Fit')

plt.axis([0, 8, 0, 2000])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This returns the following plot:

[image]

Now how can I extend the fitted (orange) curve so it goes up to x = 8? Please note that I do not want to create additional data points I just want to expand the range of the fitted curve.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define an extra data range for x to extend it beyond the data range given by your data points. You can even improve the representation and calculate more x values for the fit function:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def exponential_fit(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-b*x) + c

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([30, 50, 80, 160, 300, 580])
fitting_parameters, covariance = curve_fit(exponential_fit, x, y)
a, b, c = fitting_parameters

x_min = -4  
x_max = 8                                #min/max values for x axis
x_fit = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)   #range of x values used for the fit function
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x_fit, exponential_fit(x_fit, *fitting_parameters), '-', label='Fit')

plt.axis([x_min, x_max, 0, 2000])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

For added flexibility, I introduced `x_min, x_max`, because the same values are used to calculate the range for x values used by the fit function and to scale the axis for the plot. [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) creates an evenly spaced sample between start and stop value, used as x values to calculate the corresponding y values in the fit function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Note that it should be `np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 100)`

Comment: Edited it. Was wondering, why it worked nonetheless in my tests. But Eclipse inserted `from numpy.core.function_base import linspace` into the script. Too much automation.

Answer (score 2):

`x` ranges from 0 to 5. If you want the curve to go up to 8 ([or up to eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven)) you need to supply an array which ranges to eleven... sorry 8.

```
x_new = np.linspace(0,11)
plt.plot(x_new, exponential_fit(x_new, *fitting_parameters), '-', label='Fit')
```