# Fitting equation using the power law

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

Please how can i fit the equation below using the powerlaw

```
S_u = S_u0*(p_new/p_i)**-alpha
```

`S_u` and `p_new/p_i` are know whiles `S_u0` and `alpha` are unknowns.

Comment: You can define your own function and use it with [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). An example for this strategy [is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48507056/8881141)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to rephrase your question a little. To make your question visible to more people use the general python tag instead of python-3.x (which should only be used for version-specific questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lmfit (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) and something like

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model

# get data into numpy ndarrays.  If in a simple data file, 
# with columns of data, that might look like:
data = np.loadtxt('datafile name')
p   = data[0, :]
s_u = data[1, :]

# define your model function (independent var in first argument)
def mod_su(p, su0=1, alpha=1):  # (values used as starting guesss)
    return su0 * (p)**(-alpha)

# now define the fitting model
model = Model(mod_su)

# make a set of parameters (for 'su0' and 'alpha'):
params = model.make_params(su0=10)  # can also set initial values here

# optionally, put min/max bounds on parameters:
params['alpha'].min = 0.0
params['su0'].min = 0.0
params['su0'].max = 1e6

# run the fit with Model.fit(Data_Array, Parameters, independent vars)
result = model.fit(s_u, params, p=p)

# print report with results and fitting statistics
print(result.fit_report())

# plot data and best fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(p, s_u, label='data')
plt.plot(p, result.best_fit, label='fit')
plt.show()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @ M Newville your solution is working perfect but please do you have any idea i can extend the fit to the origin which is zero. I appreciate your assistance in advance. Due to my statues on this i cant post a figure otherwise in would have shown you how my fit should be. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it probably depends on why you cannot extend the fit to the origin. Does the model represent your data at the origin?  Does the data diverge?  If not, perhaps the model need to be changed.  I think the idea on SO is that if an answer is useful or acceptable to vote for it or accept it.  And if you have a separate question, you use a different question, not comments to your original question.