# Obtain continuous model as a function of two independent variables out of their defined range

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, lmfit

I have an array of times 
`times=[58418 58422 58424 58426 58428 58430 58540 58542 58650 58654 58656 58658
 58660 58662 58664 58666 58668 58670 58672 58674 58768 58770 58772 58774
 58776 58778 58780 58782 58784 58786 58788 58790 58792 58794 58883 58884
 58886 58888 58890 58890 58892 58894 58896 58898 58904]`

and of correspondent observed quantities
 `y_obs =[ 0.00393986  0.00522288  0.00820794  0.01102782  0.00411525  0.00297762
  0.00463183  0.00602662  0.0114886   0.00176694  0.01241464  0.01316199
  0.01108201  0.01056611  0.0107585   0.00723887  0.0082614   0.01239229
  0.00148118  0.00407329  0.00626722  0.01026926  0.01408419  0.02638901
  0.02284189  0.02142943  0.02274845  0.01315814  0.01155898  0.00985705
  0.00476936  0.00130343  0.00350376  0.00463576 -0.00610933  0.00286234
  0.00845177  0.00849791  0.0151215   0.0151215   0.00967625  0.00802465
  0.00291534  0.00819779  0.00366089]`
 and relative errors:

`y_obs_err = [6.12189334e-05 6.07487598e-05 4.66365096e-05 4.48781264e-05
 5.55250430e-05 6.18699105e-05 6.35339947e-05 6.21108524e-05
 5.55636135e-05 7.66087180e-05 4.34256323e-05 3.61131000e-05
 3.30783270e-05 2.41312040e-05 2.85080015e-05 2.96644612e-05
 4.58662869e-05 5.19419065e-05 6.00479888e-05 6.62586953e-05
 3.64830945e-05 2.58120956e-05 1.83249104e-05 1.59433858e-05
 1.33375408e-05 1.29714326e-05 1.26025166e-05 1.47293107e-05
 2.17933175e-05 2.21611713e-05 2.42946630e-05 3.61296843e-05
 4.23009806e-05 7.23405476e-05 5.59390368e-05 4.68144974e-05
 3.44773949e-05 2.32907036e-05 2.23491451e-05 2.23491451e-05
 2.92956472e-05 3.28665479e-05 4.41214301e-05 4.88142073e-05
 7.19116984e-05]`

I define a function that calculates the value of `y` as a function of the times,
a number of parameters, and another independent variable

`p= [ 2.82890497  3.75014266  5.89347542  7.91821558  2.95484056  2.13799544
  3.32575733  4.32724456  8.2490644   1.26870083  8.91397925  9.45059128
  7.95712563  7.58669608  7.72483557  5.19766853  5.93186433  8.89793105
  1.06351782  2.92471065  4.49999613  7.37354766 10.11275281 18.94787684
 16.40097363 15.38679306 16.33387783  9.44782842  8.29959664  7.07757293
  3.42450524  0.93588962  2.515773    3.32857547  7.180216    2.05522399
  6.06855409  6.1016838  10.8575614  10.8575614   6.94775991  5.76187014
  2.09327787  5.88619335  2.62859611]`

Here I define the function to calculate the `y` variable:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from lmfit import Model
import scipy.integrate as it
import scipy.constants as scc
def new_f_function(t, sum, f0, a, b,c, T0):
    n= 2 * np.pi * sum 

    obs_f = f0 + it.cumtrapz(-a * p**c + b, t-T0, initial=0)
    new_f = obs_f*(1+sum/scc.c)
    return new_f
```

I create a model, and initialize my parameters with a first guess:

```
# Create Model
model = Model(new_f_function, independent_vars=['t'])

# Initialize Parameter
params = model.make_params()

params['sum'].value = 1.483 
params['sum'].min = 1.47
params['sum'].max = 1.50

.... # and so on for the others
```

then I fit the model

```
`result = model.fit(y, params, weights=(1./y_err)), t=times, scale_covar=False)`
```

to obtain the best-fit parameters `result.best_fit`.
Finally I can plot the the best fit with

`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(3, 6), sharex='all')
ax2.plot(times, result.best_fit, label='best fit')`

My question is: how can I plot/define the function at points where the variable `p` is not defined (e.g. I have no data)?
I guess the question is similar to that here: [Scipy curve_fit: how to plot the fitted curve beyond the data points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506782/scipy-curve-fit-how-to-plot-the-fitted-curve-beyond-the-data-points)

but in a case where the function has two independent variables and, although I can define an extra data range for the x-axis variable, that is time, I can not do the same for the observed variable `p`.

Comment: Can you write down the mathematical equation of your model?

Answer (score 0):

> in a case where the function has two independent variables and, although I can define an extra data range for the x-axis variable, that is time, I can not do the same for the observed variable p.

If you have a function f(x, y) = z you have two independent input variables x and y and one output variable (this is your observed variable, if I'm right).

You can plot this by creating a 2d array (as fine as you want, independant of your times from before fitting), passing each single point to the function and plot all the calcalated z's. This cannot be plotted in a normal x-y plot obviously. One way is a 3d plot or a 2d color map plot.

Not sure if I got you right.

Comment: I don't need a 3d plot, the plot can be `y=f(x,z)` where x are the times, and z are data points of another quantity observed independently.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's an noninvertible method, got it. How about brute forcing? You can just make a list of x and a list of z and calc all y's. Then you can plot the z's against x and y.

Comment: I do not know the z besides those observed. I have the model calculated and its best fit parameters, I just need to find the method to expand it at different values where the variables are not (currently) defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your `model` object stores the function that you fit, and the best parameters for that fit are stored in the `result.best_values` property.

To to get that functions output for some set of new values, you can use the following code:

```
new_times_to_evaluate = np.array([56789, 54321])  # Or whatever values you'd like

new_predictions = model.eval(  # evaluate your model
    **result.best_values,  # unpack the dictionary of best parameters to use for evaluation
    t=new_times_to_evaluate  # evaluate on these new times
)

ax2.plot(new_times_to_evaluate, new_predictions, label='my new values')
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the unpacking with `**result.best_values`. If I try your expression it returns an `invalid syntax error`, but I believe this is on the right path.

Comment: @Py-ser What python version are you using (you can use `sys.version`)? Are you sure you didn't make any typo's? As for unpacking, you can read about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/).

Comment: It is python 2.7 (I know it is old). I can't even `print **result.best_values`(invalid syntax), but for what I read in your link and others this is the standand way to unpack dictionaries. I am pretty sure there is no typo. I'll try to dig more if it is a version issue.

Comment: Even with python3.7 returns error: `new_predictions = model.eval(**result.best_values, t=new_times)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/lmfit/model.py", line 848, in eval
    return self.func(**self.make_funcargs(params, kwargs))
  File "main.py", line 88, in new_f_function
        obs_f = f0 + it.cumtrapz(-a * p**c + b, t-T0, initial=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 333, in cumtrapz
    raise ValueError("If given, length of x along axis must be the "
ValueError: If given, length of x along axis must be the same as y.`

Comment: have you realized there are 2 independent variables in the model? That might be the reason of the returned error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you asking to evaluate the best-fit model at points other than those you used for the fit.  FWIW, this is a fine thing to need to do, either to interpolate or extrapolate the model outside of the fit range.

To do that, just do:

```
 result = model.fit(y, params, weights=(1./y_err)), t=times, 
                    scale_covar=False)
 predicted = result.eval(t=new_times)
```

Just read that as "evaluate the result at new times".

Comment: I think `eval()` takes two arguments?

Comment: @Py-ser: `ModelResult.eval()` has only optional arguments and will default to using its own `params`, so that here `result.eval()` will use `result.params` (the best-fit parameters) and give exactly `result.best_fit`.   By default, it will also use the independent variables (here `t`) used in the fit, but the user wants to use different values for the independent variable.

Comment: It gives me the error: `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lmfit/model.py", line 848, in eval
    return self.func(**self.make_funcargs(params, kwargs))
TypeError: new_f_function() takes exactly 6 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: give a complete, minimal example that shows the problem and a full traceback.   And, (judging from line number and a very incomplete message) make sure you are using `result.eval()`, not `model.eval()`.  FWIW, Python2.7 is no longer supported.

Comment: You are right, I was using `model.eval()` instead of `result.eval()`. However, even using `result.eval(t=new_times)` gets me the error: `ValueError: If given, length of x along axis must be the same as y.`

Comment: nope, that is how it works.  really, no kidding. In the future, you'll want to give a complete, minimal example that shows the problem and a full traceback.  Also: pay attention in detail when someone offers an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211248/discussion-between-py-ser-and-m-newville).

Comment: @MNewwille have you realized there are 2 independent variables in the model? That might be the reason of the returned error.

Comment: That is incorrect:  In your question, you define your model explicitly to have exactly 1 independent parameter, `t`.  Again: in the future, you will want to post a complete, minimal example that shows a problem, and the full traceback.  Your question was answered (pretty simple, actually) and follow-up comments were given.  I cannot force you to understand these, but you have sort of gone out of your way to demonstrate that you are not even reading your own question, let alone the answer.